# I am trying to upload an Excel file into big query to create a table and I am getting a 'Bad character (ASCII 0)' error

Tags: sql, excel, google-bigquery

I am trying to upload an Excel file into big query to create a table and I am getting this error:

> Failed to create table: Error while reading data, error message:
> Error detected while parsing row starting at position: 0. Error: Bad
> character (ASCII 0) encountered. File:
> gs://nyc-car-crashes/Motor_Vehicle_Collisions_Details.xlsx

I didn't manually type in any commands to load the data, I just used the create table menu that Big Query has.

I tried loading the file into BQ by selecting 'create table' in the dataset I wanted to import the data into. From the create table menu I pulled the data from my google cloud storage and set the file format to CSV. I selected native table for the table type. I selected to auto-detect the schema.

Im not sure how to fix the issue. I tried using = CLEAN to all data in each column -> copy and paste values -> split text to columns to fix the data types.

After this, the error was still coming up when I tried uploading the file.

What do I need to do to get the file uploaded into the dataset?

Comment: Hi - please update your question to explain how you are loading this file into BQ e.g. the command(s) you are running

Comment: I just figured out the issue. I saved the file as a CSV UTF-8. and that loaded in fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is your file is in XLSX format, you need to save it as CSV file first, then upload the file again. There are only 7 accepted file formats when you want to get the data from cloud storage, here are the following:

1. CSV
2. JSONL
3. Avro
4. Parquet
5. ORC
6. Cloud Datastore Backup
7. Iceberg

since XLSX is not included, you will receive this error:

> Bad character (ASCII 0) encountered.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why, but here is what worked for me:

1. Save the file in .xlsx locally
2. Open in a local location where you saved .xlsx and save as .csv
3. Upload in BQ the newly saved .csv

I hope this works for you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).